# Compile error(undefined reference to ~ ) with static linking

Tags: static, linker, gem5

I'm trying to build(compile) the graph500 benchmark in gem5 se mode.

But there is a problem and the following error occurs.

First I'm using the latest version (version 3) of the graph500, and I'm trying to build the graph500 statically to run on Gem5 se mode.

In the process, I heard somewhere that all files should exist as .a, so I downloaded libdmacm-1.1.0, libibverbs-1.2.1 and libnl from the Internet, and I gave the --enable-static option to finish making installation.

Anyway..the following error messages keep happening, and it's harder than I thought to solve them

```
/usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.a(dl_dlopen_module.o): In function `dlopen_open':
dl_dlopen_module.c:(.text+0x413): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/local/lib/libopen-rte.a(plm_rsh_module.o): In function `setup_launch':
plm_rsh_module.c:(.text+0xfc9): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.a(if.o): In function `opal_ifaddrtoname':
if.c:(.text+0x2e4): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/local/lib/libopen-rte.a(ras_slurm_module.o): In function `init':
ras_slurm_module.c:(.text+0x69a): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.a(evutil.o): In function `evutil_unparse_protoname':
/home/caslab/sjkim/bench/graph500/src/openmpi-4.1.5/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent/evutil.c:758
: warning: Using 'getprotobynumber' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/local/lib/libnl-3.a(lib_libnl_3_la-utils.o): In function `nl_str2ip_proto':
/home/caslab/sjkim/bench/graph500/src/libnl/lib/utils.c:875: warning: Using 'getprotobyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/local/lib/librdmacm.a(src_librdmacm_la-cma.o): In function `rdma_init_qp_attr':
/home/caslab/sjkim/bench/graph500_3/src/librdmacm-1.1.0/src/cma.c:1038: undefined reference to `ibv_copy_qp_attr_from_kern'
/usr/local/lib/librdmacm.a(src_librdmacm_la-cma.o): In function `ucma_copy_ud_event':
/home/caslab/sjkim/bench/graph500_3/src/librdmacm-1.1.0/src/cma.c:2079: undefined reference to `ibv_copy_ah_attr_from_kern'
/usr/local/lib/librdmacm.a(src_librdmacm_la-cma.o): In function `ucma_query_route':
/home/caslab/sjkim/bench/graph500_3/src/librdmacm-1.1.0/src/cma.c:801: undefined reference to `ibv_copy_path_rec_from_kern'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'graph500_reference_bfs_sssp' failed
make: *** [graph500_reference_bfs_sssp] Error 1
root@caslab-X12DAi-N6:/home/caslab/sjkim/bench/graph500_3/src#
```

What should I do?

If anyone knows and cares about this, I'd really appreciate it!!

I was trying to build through the following makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Drestrict=__restrict__ -O3 -DGRAPH_GENERATOR_MPI -DREUSE_CSR_FOR_VALIDATION -I../aml
#CFLAGS = -static -Drestrict=__restrict__ -O3 -DGRAPH_GENERATOR_MPI -DREUSE_CSR_FOR_VALIDATION -I../aml
#LDFLAGS = -static -lpthread -lmpi -lc -lpthread -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -lrt -lz  -libverbs -lrdmacm -ldl -lutil -lnl-route-3 -lnl-3 -ldl
#LDFLAGS = -static -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/lib/infiniband -lrdmacm -lpthread -lmpi -lc -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -lrt -lz  -libverbs -ldl -lutil -lnl-route-3 -lnl-3 -ldl
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/lib/infiniband  -static
MPICC = mpicc

all: graph500_reference_bfs_sssp graph500_reference_bfs
#all: graph500_reference_bfs
#graph500_custom_bfs graph500_custom_bfs_sssp

GENERATOR_SOURCES = ../generator/graph_generator.c ../generator/make_graph.c ../generator/splittable_mrg.c ../generator/utils.c
SOURCES = main.c utils.c validate.c ../aml/aml.c
HEADERS = common.h csr_reference.h bitmap_reference.h

graph500_reference_bfs_sssp: bfs_reference.c $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES) csr_reference.c sssp_reference.c
        $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) -DSSSP $(LDFLAGS) -o graph500_reference_bfs_sssp bfs_reference.c sssp_reference.c csr_reference.c $(SOURCES) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES)
graph500_reference_bfs: bfs_reference.c $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES) csr_reference.c
        $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o graph500_reference_bfs bfs_reference.c csr_reference.c $(SOURCES) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES) -lm
graph500_custom_bfs: bfs_custom.c $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES) csr_reference.c
        $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o graph500_custom_bfs bfs_custom.c csr_reference.c $(SOURCES) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES) -lm

graph500_custom_bfs_sssp: bfs_custom.c sssp_custom.c $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES) csr_reference.c
        $(MPICC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o graph500_custom_bfs_sssp bfs_custom.c sssp_custom.c csr_reference.c $(SOURCES) $(GENERATOR_SOURCES) -lm

clean:
        -rm -f graph500_*
```

The annotated parts here are the ones I tried and failed.